# Complex layout GUI

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I'm working on some AutoCAD plugin for my company and I was considering some layouts for it. However, I cannot spend a ridiculus amount of time on the look of the application. I need something resonably fast to deliver that will improve the global user experience. That said, I don't think I can get too far away from Winforms or WPF (Winform being my comfort zone, but I know the advantages of WPF and might have to expend my zone of comfort).

The main thing I'm trying to acheive is a "floating" multi-panel interface where you can "slide out" additionnal options and such. Imagine a form that has a list of projects in a list view or grid view and when you select one, a panel slides on the left of the form with a list of all the items involved in that projet. That's pretty much what I'm trying to do but there will be more then one panel like that.

I have tried different approches in Winforms such as:

- Split Pannels - I found the layout limitations too high to be usable
- Using seperated forms instead of panel - The maintenance would become a nightmare...

Is there another Winform alternative or should I move on to WPF? If I move on to WPF, what exactly is the feature I should be looking for to acheive my goals?

Comment: IMHO, the fastest way to achieve high quality UIs with non-standard behavior is to use a UI library like DevExpress or Component One.

Comment: I don't know of any - but there still might be one.

Comment: Looking at it right now but it has a lot of limitations too.

Comment: Personally I prefer WPF for its UI flexibility. I remember trying to customize the UI in WinForms a while back, and I had sooo many problems with it. Now that I've switched to WPF's "lookless" controls, I never want to go back. But if you're more comfortable with WinForms, I'd look for a solution with that first, as WPF has a bit of a learning curve to it and you said you can't spend a lot of time on the look of your application.

Comment: Switching to WPF wouldn't be time stricly invested in UI design however. If you'r talking about 10 to 20 hours, this shouldn't be a problem. If you'r talking about 100 to 200 hours, then yea, I can't afford that. I have strong bases in ASP.NET MVC web developpement so the MVVC (or w/e the acronym is) doesn't really scare me. I'm all for data layer and logic layer abstraction.

Comment: Just as an information: Winforms used to be my comfort zone. I've been developing with WPF for almost 2 years now. When I have to support my old Winforms Application, it's a REAL pain. WPF made everything sooooo easier/cleaner that I honestly have trouble coming back to Winforms. If you want a very flexible UI component, have you looked at `AvalonDock` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the general consent is that WPF is more flexible but to achieve extensive customization with moderated to little amount of work, a UI library would be required. Also, it seems there isn't a whole lot of "good" free frameworks and I would need to buy something like [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/), [Component One](http://www.componentone.com/) or [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [DockPanel Suite](http://dockpanelsuite.sourceforge.net/) for an effect similar to an IDE.
It supports floating and docked Panels, including hiding nesting and saving layouts.

Relatively easy to use, though documentation isn't amazing, and available as a NuGet package.